# TCP segments disappearing

Tags: c#, tcp

I run into a problem that googling seems can't solve. To keep it simple I have a client written in C# and a server running Linux written in C. Client is calling Send(buffer) in a loop 100 times. The problem is that server receives only a dozen of them. If I put a sleep, big enough, in a loop everything turns out fine. The buffer is small - about 30B. I read about Nagle's algorithm and ACK delay but it doesn't answer my problems.

```
          for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          { 
            try
            {                  
                client.Send(oneBuffer, 0, oneBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None)                    
            }
            catch (SocketException socE)
            {
                if ((socE.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock)
                  || (socE.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                  || (socE.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending))
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("Never happens :(");
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100); //problem solver but why??

          }
```

It's look like send buffer gets full and rejects data until it gets empty again, in blocking mode and nonblocking mode. Even better, I never get any exception!? I would expect some of the exceptions to raise but nothing. :( Any ideas? Thnx in advance.

Comment: I would analyze the TCP traffic first (use WireShark on the Windows PC and tcpdump on the Linux server!).

Comment: What other SocketExceptions are occurring? You are swallowing some. How do you close the socket? Use Shutdown(Send). Show the Linux server code.

Comment: What do you exactly receive on server side ? Does the dozen of packets received contains the whole data or not ?

Comment: Let me guess: you assume that recv will read entire "messages" or one "buffer" at a time?

Comment: @kol I will do that for sure

Comment: @usr There were no exceptions on client side. I assume that recv reads one "buffer" at a time.

Comment: @AlexH The packets contained the whole data on the server (but I figured that later :S).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was naive thinking there was a problem with TCP stack. It was with my server code. Somewhere in between the data manipulation I used strncpy() function on a buffer that stores messages. Every message contained \0 at the end. Strncpy copied only the first message (the first string) out of the buffer regardless the count that was given (buffer length). That resulted in me thinking I had lost messages.

When I used the delay between send() calls on client, messages didn't get buffered. So, strncpy() worked on a buffer with one message and everything went smoothly. That "phenomenon" led we into thinking that speed rate of send calls is causing my problems.

Again thanks on help, your comments made me wonder. :)

Answer (score 2):

TCP is stream oriented. This means that `recv` can read any amount of bytes between one and the total number of bytes outstanding (sent but not yet read). "Messages" do not exist. Sent buffers can be split or merged.

There is no way to get message behavior from TCP. There is no way to make `recv` read at least N bytes. Message semantics are constructed *by the application protocol*. Often, by using fixed-size messages or a length prefix. You can read at least N bytes by doing a read loop.

Remove that assumption from your code.

Comment: Yes, yes, of course. I was aware of that. Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. I never had that assumption. :) I rarely write something in English so don't express myself very good, sorry. Again, thnx on help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is due to the [nagle algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.nodelay.aspx) :

> The Nagle algorithm is designed to reduce network traffic by causing
>   the socket to buffer small packets and then combine and send them in
>   one packet under certain circumstances. A TCP packet consists of 40
>   bytes of header plus the data being sent. When small packets of data
>   are sent with TCP, the overhead resulting from the TCP header can
>   become a significant part of the network traffic. On heavily loaded
>   networks, the congestion resulting from this overhead can result in
>   lost datagrams and retransmissions, as well as excessive propagation
>   time caused by congestion. The Nagle algorithm inhibits the sending of
>   new TCP segments when new outgoing data arrives from the user if any
>   previouslytransmitted data on the connection remains unacknowledged.

Calling client.Send function doesn't mean a TCP segment will be sent.
In your case, as buffers are small, the naggle algorithm will regroup them into larger segments. Check on server side that the dozen of buffers received contains the whole data.

When you add a Thread.Sleep(100), you will receive 100 packets on server side because nagle algotithm won't wait longer for further data.

If you really need a short latency in your application, you can explicitly disable nagle algorithm for your TcpClient : set the [NoDelay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay.aspx) property to true. Add this line at the begening of your code :

```
client.NoDelay = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, but there wasn't problem with Nagle. I did my homework and read everything I could find including Nagle before posting here a question. :)