# Recv method usage

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking

I'm making a multiplayer game and I have an issue with the recv function ( or the send one , not sure ).

Server side code :

```
        char* UserName = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(UserName,256);
        recv(sConnect,UserName,256,0);

        char* Password = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(Password,256);
        recv(sConnect,Password,256,0);


        users[ ++usercount ] = new Client(UserName,Password,sConnect);

        if( users[usercount] ->GetLogInSuccesful() )
        {
            if( send(sConnect,"0x0001",6,0) == 0)
                 cout << "THIS IS **** UP";
        }
        else
        {
            usercount--;
            send(sConnect,"0x0002",6,0);
        }
```

Client side code :

```
        send(server->getsConnect(),User,256,0); // works
        send(server->getsConnect(),Pass,256,0); // works
        char* Response = new char[6];
        ZeroMemory(Response,6);
        recv(server->getsConnect(),Response,6,0); // gets stuck here.
```

I'm probably blind and don't see where the mistake is, but got tired of looking at it after 2 hours. It would be nice if anyone could point me in the right direction.

***Edit due to comments:***

I have checked the send function ( also editted the code ), The console stays clean therefore the send function is working properly.

Wierd thing is, when I first added the if i forgot the { } and it went into the else. The client recv worked for the second send ( send(sConnect,"0x0002",6,0); )

***Edit due to answere***

In the client constructor the username and the Password are both checked, therefore the recv's in the server side and the sends in the client side both work perfectly.

It is only something about that first send in the server side since the second works.

***Edit due to comments && answeres #2***

Due to Remy's answere I actually found out there was a bug in my Client constructor, and I fixed it. Now both brenches of send don't work :).

This is basically the login of a game, The client inputs the username and the password and sends them to the server. Then a used is created based on the fact that the password and the username are right or not. GetLogInSuccesful just returns a bool from the client function that tells me if the password and the username were right or not.

***Edit due to Solving***

Looks like there was anthoner thread using the recv function, and that the send was taken by the other recv... I hate such stupid mistakes. Thnx for all the help and the advices!

Comment: Tangential:  Why do you think you need to dynamically allocate char buffers?

Comment: @JohnDibling - maybe the intention is to, (eventually), queue off the pointer to another thread?

Comment: @MartinJames:  Maybe, but it sure didn't look like it to my eyes.

Comment: Also, how do you *know* the `send` worked?  You aren't checking return codes.

Comment: Since, I won't use it during the whole program, I prefer being able to delete it after using it.

Comment: How about using a TCP/IP test tool and use that as a client to see if it's the client or the server which is not working properly?

Comment: Used the watch mode, and after those recv on the server side the Password and the UserName fileds are correct.

Comment: You should prefer automatic allocations unless you have a compelling need for dynamic allocation.  Your preference would be met very nicely with `char UserName [256]` because it will be destroyed at the end of the scope in which it was declared.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't mean the `send` worked from the server side.  Check your return codes.

Comment: Send may also return `0` which indicates a closed stream rather than `SOCKET_ERROR`

Comment: I also checked with 0, same resault.

Comment: I'm no longer convinced my answer will solve the immediate problem (although you should fix the bug mentioned there). My advice: create a very simple repro by removing stuff. Remove the password, and always send the same response. Simplify, until the bug is gone. That tells you what piece of code caused it.; Also, I'm not convinced the bug is visible in the code snippets given here.

Comment: Question. What do you change in order to branch to the "LogIn" failure? The key might be there?

Comment: I debugged both the server and the client over 30 times already, that basically means I went in a run through each line and checked all the values and such. The server works normally ( finishes the for, the send seems to be correct and so on ). The Client stops at the recv function.

Comment: @taigitanaka using the debugger is good but we know there is a bug. The TCP stack is not buggy. You can either stare at the code for another 2 hours, or start to make some changes. Simplifying *will* eventually remove the hanging, don't you agree?

Comment: @mnunberg No, send() *cannot* return zero indicating a closed connection. Only recv() and friends do that. If you send to a closed connection you will get -1 with errno = ECONNRESET.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its solution had nothing to do with the information provided and is of no permanent value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that `recv` returns all bytes at once. It could also legally return just one byte. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19403976/122718) for a more complete description of the problem.

This problem hits all TCP beginners.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, but this doesn't explain why the client-side recv doesn't work (as in, gets stuck)

Comment: The code is certainly wrong, but the client only does `recv` once -- It's the server that's doing multiple `recv` without checking the return values. But according to the @op the client is hanging on the first `recv` call it makes

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a response if `GetLogInSuccessful()` fails:

```
if( ...->GetLogInSuccesful() )
    send(sConnect,"0x0001",6,0);
else
    send(sConnect,"0x0000",6,0);
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you but here is how things actually work. At start usercount = 0; then I call users[ ++usercount] = ...; that increments usercount to 1 first, and then calls users[1] = ...; therefore I do call the right things. What you are saying would be true If I would be using usercount++;

Comment: Why would you not want to store anything in `users[0]`? In any case, my comment about `send()` still stands.

Comment: Because I don't like things that start at 0, it is just wierd. I prefer starting with 1 and ending at n instead of starting with 0 and ending at n-1.